# Как проверить наличие алиаса в шаблоне с помощью concept?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, c++20, метапрограммирование, concept

Как в концепте с++20 проверить наличие алиаса внутри шаблонного типа?

```
struct example {
    using alias_t = int;
};

template<class T>
concept example_concept = requires{
        T::alias_t;
};
```

Вот пример, если передать example в качестве шаблонного параметра аля `template<example_concept T>` код не будет компилироваться. Как правильно сделать эту проверку ?

update

```
template<class T>
concept future_traits = requires {
    typename T::initial_awaitable_t;
    typename T::await_awaitable_t;
    typename T::final_awaitable_t;
};


template<class return_type>
struct default_traits {
    using initial_awaitable_t = std::suspend_always;
    using await_awaitable_t   = detail::symmetrical_awaitable<detail::promise<return_type, default_traits>>;
    using final_awaitable_t   = detail::final_awaitable;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы не поверите, `typename T::alias_t;`.

Comment: А в VС++  и этого не требуется, и так все компилируется и работает...

Comment: а если таких алиасов несколько? с одним работает, через точку с запятой не работает

Comment: @DenverToha Работает. Код в студию.

Comment: @Harry В какой-то момент показалось, что MSVC превращается в нормальный компилятор, но у них до сих пор самые смачные баги. (¬‿¬)

Comment: Ну... давайте называть это расширениями :)

Comment: добавил реальный код в вопрос

Comment: ошибка компиляции
error: constraints not satisfied for class template 'promise' [with return_type = int, traits_type = runpine::traits::default_traits<int>]
            using await_awaitable_t   = detail::symmetrical_awaitable<detail::promise<return_type, default_traits>>;

Comment: @DenverToha Тут работает: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/nGso5jf9q Вероятно в юзингах что-то не то написано, и компилятор их не проверял, пока вы не тыкнули в них концептом. Нужен [mcve].

Comment: думаю вы правы, но пример будет через чур большим((( а что в юзингах может быть не то? это же просто проверка имен(как я это себе представляю)

Comment: @DenverToha Ну значит нет таких типов, на которые они ссылаются. Причем отсутствующие типы скорее всего зависят от шаблонных параметров, а то компилятор бы раньше заметил. *"будет через чур большим"* Так в том и дело, что весь код от вас не нужен. От вас нужно его ужать до такого примера, который показывает проблему, и в котором нет ничего лишнего.